# Facebook Gifts: How to access information about given gifts via Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

Is it possible to access information about given gifts via Open Graph? I haven't found any information about this in the developers documentation. A simple, it is not possible (yet), would be very useful.

Where can I find more information about this new Facebook feature from a developers perspective? Has no developer thought about this, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not yet possible to access this sort of information via Facebook Platform. As the Gifts feature is still only running as a test to a small amount of users, I wouldn't expect an API for it to launch, if at all, until after it is available to a larger percentage of users.